# What was the mathematical notation for stopping at a certain digit and rolling over?

Tags: notation

For example, if I were to calculate time, I would do:

```
6 + 8 = ? (That mathematical notation here) 12
```

Such that the answer would be 2, not 14.

I remember last seeing it while working on mathematical encryption.

Comment: Modular arithmetic.  Which generalizes to quotienting an arbitrary ring $R$ by one of its ideals $I \subset R$.

Comment: Yes, that's it thank you. Post that as an answer.

Comment: @DLeftAdjointtoU I realized too late. comment deleted.